# hiding collapable menu on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just found this basic JavaScript for what I need for a collapsible menu. Is there away to have it so the hidden content doesn't load up first?

I have it appearing on page load in the css for accessibility if a visitor is visiting with JavaScript turned off, but I would like this code on page load to not show the hidden menu.

Also, is there away to animate it to so it looks nicer when it collapses and expands?

```
function toggleMenu(objID) {
    if (!document.getElementById) return;
    var ob = document.getElementById(objID).style;
    ob.display = (ob.display == 'none')?'block': 'none';
}
```

Comment: Why have you tagged jQuery if your not using it? Having said that, it *is* a solution to your animation needs. Is it available to you?

Comment: okay do you have any suggestions, where to point me in the right direction. I've been searching for 5 and half hours straight. It's 4am here